# Giving Access to my Datalab instance to other users via service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datalab

I have a project with 3 datalab instances and i have 6 users ,there is no way to give access to a particular instance (like i want instance 1 to be accessed only by user 1 and 3 , not by others and so on) .
I can add all 6 users to my project but in that case all will have access to all the instances(i.e will have Project level access) but i want instance level access .

Comment: https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1203#issuecomment-282126662

Answer (score 2):

There's more details in the linked issue, but the TL;DR is:

1. Use the `--service-account` flag in the `datalab create` command to assign a different service account to each instance.
2. For each user, grant the the `compute.instanceAdmin` IAM role.
3. Additionally, for each user, grant them the `iam.serviceAccountActor` IAM role, but *only for the service account tied to their instance*.

That should result in each user only having the ability to access their instance.

Note, though, that you need a separate Datalab instance for each user (i.e. don't share instances), otherwise they will wind up stepping on each others toes due to there being no separation between users (Datalab is a single-user environment).